# Facing error while running tcl script with an argument using source command

Tags: arguments, tcl

I am trying to source a tcl script inside another script using source command . The syntax i am using is as follows :

```
source /path/script.tcl vikas         #vikas is as a argument to the script
```

But i am facing an issue while executing it. Th the error i am getting is as follows:

```
TCLERR: couldn't read file "/path/script.tcl vikas" : no such file or directory.
```

kindly help me with the solution .

Thank You !

Comment: There is no way to pass parameters to the sourced script.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to do the same task ?

Comment: A sourced script should define new commands. You then can call a newly defined command and pass it parameters as usual.

Answer (score 2):

The `source` command doesn't pass arguments; it *just* reads the script in and evaluates it (with a minor nuance for `info script`).

How would you expect the arguments to be seen by the script? If it is via the `argv` global variable, then you can just set that up before calling `source`. It's not special at all except that `tclsh` and `wish` write the list of arguments to it during start up.

You can script things easily enough.

```
proc sourceWithArguments {filename args} {
    global argv
    set old $argv
    try {
        set argv $args
        uplevel "#0" [list source $filename]
    } finally {
        # Restore the original arguments at the end
        set argv $old
    }
}
```

Comment: The `#0` is in quotes just because of the syntax highlighter being a bit dumb.

Answer (score 1):

The `source <file>` command simply reads the commands in `<file>` almost just like you copy-pasted the commands.

If you have a main file and other file which is sourced from the main file, then you could just set a variable in the main file and use that variable in the sourced file.

```
# sourced.tcl
puts $parameter_from_main
```

```
# main.tcl
set parameter_from_main "Hello"
source sourced.tcl
```

In this case, both the main.tcl and sourced.tcl files are running in the same global scope.  Some people may dislike this solution because you can get namespace pollution, but it might be good enough for what you need to do.